# Array push - change name on key

Tags: php, arrays, array-push, array-key

I can not get this to work. 
How do I change key `[0]` to `[id]`. In the below array ex. I want the `[0] => 2` to look like `[id] => 2`

**Array ex.:**

```
Array
(
    [pickup] => 2014/11/10 15:15
    [tire_front] => tire_front
    [service] => 4
    [message] => 
    [user] => 1
    [0] => 2
)
```

**My php script:**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['rep_list'])) {
    //insert database connect script here 
    $workCard = $_POST['rep_list'];
    array_push($workCard, $id); 
    print_r($workCard) ."<br>"; 
}
else{
    echo("errorrrrr");
}
?>
```

---

**SOLVED**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['rep_list'])) {
    //insert database connect script here 
    $workCard = $_POST['rep_list'];
    $workCard['id'] = $id;
    print_r($workCard) ."<br>"; 
}
else{
    echo("errorrrrr");
}
?>
```

Comment: `$a['id'] = $a[0]; unset($a[0]);` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use `array_push` for this

```
$workCard['id'] = $id;
```

If it is already setted you can `unset($workCard[0])`

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$workCard['id'] = $id;
```